# What am I missing in this code for my first rotating banner?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a rotating banner and everything seems ok except I keep getting the error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'** at line 54. I am not very experienced and just started codding so everything is a bit blurry still. Also I haven't even seen some of the stuff on this code but I followed a tutorial and the end result is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-banner" id="main-banner">
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban3">

    </div>
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban2">

    </div>
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban1">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var bannerStatus = 1;
    var bannerTimer = 4000;

    window.onload = function (){
        bannerLoop();
    }

    var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function(){
        bannerLoop();
    }, bannerTimer);

function bannerLoop() {
    if (bannerStatus === 1) {

    document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "0";
        
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "0px";
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "-1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "1500";
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "500";
        }, 500);
}
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "1";
        }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 2;
    }

        else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
    document.getElementById("imgban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "0px";
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
    document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "-1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "1500";
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "500";
        }, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.opacity = "1";
        }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 3;
    }
    else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
    document.getElementById("imgban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "0px";
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "-1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "1500";
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "1200px";
        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "500";
        }, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.opacity = "1";
        }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 1;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've checked and eveything seems fine, what am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide better code example, problem is probably above code you provided

Comment: Hi there. And welcome to StackOverflow. :-) Please add more to your code example. Or at least let us know which line is line 54 of your code example. :-D

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to paste the code into a template D:

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the awful indentation.
Keeping a clean indentation in your code is really important to see where a block opens and closes.

By fixing the indentation, I spotted 3 misplaced `}` characters.
There were 2 extras in the first if statement, and 1 was missing at the end.

The code below is intended better, though not perfect, and the `}` symbols are corrected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="main-banner" id="main-banner">
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban3">

    </div>
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban2">

    </div>
    <div class="imgban" id="imgban1">

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var bannerStatus = 1;
    var bannerTimer = 4000;

    window.onload = function (){
        bannerLoop();
    }

    var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function(){
        bannerLoop();
    }, bannerTimer);

    function bannerLoop() {
      if (bannerStatus === 1) {

        document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "0";
          
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "0px";
          document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
          document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "-1200px";
          document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "1500";
          document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "1200px";
          document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "500";
        }, 500);
      
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("imgban2").style.opacity = "1";
          }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 2;
      
      } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {
        document.getElementById("imgban3").style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "0px";
            document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
            document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "-1200px";
            document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "1500";
            document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "1200px";
            document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "500";
          }, 500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("imgban3").style.opacity = "1";
          }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 3;
      } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {
        document.getElementById("imgban1").style.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById("imgban3").style.right = "0px";
          document.getElementById("imgban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
          document.getElementById("imgban1").style.right = "-1200px";
          document.getElementById("imgban1").style.zIndex = "1500";
          document.getElementById("imgban2").style.right = "1200px";
          document.getElementById("imgban2").style.zIndex = "500";
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById("imgban1").style.opacity = "1";
        }, 1000);
        bannerStatus = 1;
      }
  }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```